# problem with the phase portrait of a equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have to analyze the phase portrait of this equation:

$\dot{x}=y \\\dot{y}=x+\alpha y-x^{3}+6\alpha xy^{2}$

I´ve already checked when $\alpha=0$, i.e

$\dot{x}=y \\\dot{y}=x-x^{3}$

i got a saddle point in the origin and centers in $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ which are the singular points of the equation, in fact i just have to check $(1,0)$ and the same happens with $(-1,0)$

Now I´m trying to check what happens with $\alpha\neq 0$, first if $\alpha>0$ i got a saddle point in the origin again but i have problems to said what happens in $(1,0)$ or $(-1,0)$

I did something wrong? because i´m stuck in that point, i think that must be not to difficult to analyze, thank for any comments!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- Find the three critical points $(0,0), (1,0), (-1,0)$.
- Find the Jacobian matrix $J(x,y)$.
- Evaluate the eigenvalues at 'each' critical point of the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: i got $\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 -2& \alpha 
\end{bmatrix}$ in $(1,0)$ and the same for $(-1,0)$ and that means i got centers... something like an ellipse... right? But that doesn´t check with the origin in the phase portrait

Comment: Now, you can find the eigenvalues as $(1/2)(\alpha \pm sqrt{a^2 - 8})$. So what happens when $\alpha$ is zero, positive, negative with the eigenvalues at this critical point?

Comment: if $\alpha=0$ i got imaginary eigenvalues, if $\alpha>0$ both eigenvalues are positive and if $\alpha<0$ both are negative

Comment: How are you getting that? $\sqrt{a^2-8}$ is what when $a = 0, 1, 2$

Comment: $\sqrt{\alpha ^2-8}$ is imaginary for $\left | \alpha \right |< \sqrt{8}$ and $\sqrt{\alpha ^2-8}=0$ if $\alpha=\sqrt{8}$

Comment: Okay, so now figure out what happens to the eigenvalues over these ranges and the type of points they are and then repeat for the other two critical points.

Comment: You know your phase portraits! +1